# Why doesn’t my transaction inside of a stored procedure print the error message I want?

Tags: mysql, transactions, rollback

```
USE COLLEGE; 


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Fix_Egghead1;

DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE Fix_Egghead1()
BEGIN
    -- Setup error handing
    DECLARE errorOccurred INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(255);

    -- Called when an error occurs 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN 
        SET errorOccurred = TRUE;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            errorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    END ;

       START TRANSACTION;

                 DELETE FROM Student
                 WHERE Student.ID= 57; 

           INSERT INTO Faculty(LastName, FirstName, Email, HireDate, Salary, DepartmentID) 
           VALUES('Egghead', 'Eduardo', 'EduardoEgghead@College.edu', 115000, 1);



       IF errorOccurred = TRUE THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT  CONCAT( 'The faculty member wasn't succesfully added to the Faculty table:' ,  errorMessage) AS Results; 
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
        SELECT 'The faculty member  was successfully added to the Faculty table.';
    END IF;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL Fix_Egghead1();
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating a transaction rollback in which I created a stored procedure that either outputs whether the faculty member was added successfully or not added successfully to the faculty table, but the problem was that my code didn't print out the error message that it needed to print out. I know it was not a successfully transaction because Faculty member Eduardo Egghead still had a registration record as a student. How can I solve this problem? However, I did come up with one solution and the solution was to get rid of the CONCAT function and just simply write in the error message using the SELECT statement just like I did for the commit part. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it even compile with those misplaced quotes?

Comment: ```wasn't``` needs to be ```wasn\'t```

Comment: @ mustaccio Yes, it does. That's not my problem. Please read the description again. Do you think you can help?

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher Can you help?

Comment: @Jemshit Iskenderov Can you help?

Comment: @User445555 no, wait for people's answer

Comment: If you've got a version that doesn't have the quote issue, perhaps you should update the listing in the question so that people can see what you're doing and better help you?  It would also be nice if you included what DOES get printed out.  If it's returning NULL, then I'd guess that CONCAT is trying to merge in a NULL -- behavior for CONCAT is to return NULL if anything in there is a NULL.  Maybe try wrapping in IFNULL?  (Or use CONCAT_WS, or...)

Comment: @ A C  It results in NULL. That's not what should be printed out.

Comment: @A C concat_ws() doesn't work at all.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Did you get an error message or some unexpected result?  In either case, the text of the result would be helpful.  When you tried CONCAT_WS, did you give it the correct arguments?  First argument is the separator, so you'd do `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', "The faculty member wasn't succesfully added to the Faculty table:", errorMessage) AS Results;`

FWIW, the CONCAT/IFNULL version would look like: `SELECT CONCAT("The faculty member wasn't succesfully added to the Faculty table: ", IFNULL(errorMessage,'NULL')) AS Results;`

Comment: @A C, Let me try again.

Comment: @A.C- It works!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments:

I'm guessing that if the issue isn't the unescaped quote, then it's that `CONCAT()` is trying to concatenate a `NULL`.  The behavior of [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is to return `NULL` if any of its inputs is `NULL`.  I'd suggest either using [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) or wrapping your variables in an [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', "The faculty member wasn't succesfully added to the Faculty table:", errorMessage) AS Results;
-- or --
SELECT CONCAT("The faculty member wasn't succesfully added to the Faculty table: ", IFNULL(errorMessage,'NULL')) AS Results;
```